# How to store additional data in MongoDB 2.4.x such that it conforms to geoJSON formatting

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geojson

I have a database collection that follows the geoJSON formatting for geographic point locations. This allows me to easily extract data from the database for display using d3.js. If the geo referenced point contains a dataset of its own, what is the best way to store this information such that it conforms to the geoJSON formatting and permits MongoDB 2.4.x `2dsphere` queries?

Here is an example given from the geoJSON [documentation](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html)

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [123456, 234567]
  },
  "properties": {
    "arrivalTime": 12345678,
    "departureTime": 23456789
  }
}
```

Let's assume at this particular point I have a matrix of additional information, where each matrix entry is give by the value pairs `x,y,z`. For example, if `x` and `y` are 1x10 vectors, `z` is a 10x10 matrix. I need to store this type of information for this point, but I don't want to loose the ability to use `2dsphere` queries in MongoDB 2.4.x and I want my database collection to conform to geoJSON so that other libraries such as d3.js are able to interact without loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to put the GeoJSON object inside a field in a document. For example, if a location has a GeoJSON object like your example, you can embed this document inside a document that encapsulates all information regarding this location, e.g.:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId(...),
  "geo": <GeoJSON object>,
  "meta": {
    "x": [1x10 vector],
    "y": [1x10 vector],
    "z": [10x10 matrix],
    "other": <other relevant meta information>
  }
}
```

You can still index the geo location in MongoDB by specifying the sub-document:

```
> db.geo.createIndex({'geo.geometry': '2dsphere'})
```

Please note that 2.4 is not supported anymore, and there are major improvements to the 2dsphere index in 2.6 and above which includes the capability to index more GeoJSON types (see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/2dsphere/#dsphere-version-2). The latest MongoDB version is currently 3.4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the input. As for the version, I'm using MongoDB in Raspbian Jessie and the only version available through `apt-get` is version 2.4.x. The latest version of MongoDB isn't officially supported on ARM as far as I know. Once I move to a production environment, I'll obviously upgrade. I just wanted to be sure I didn't shoot myself in the foot early on prototyping.